# Фальстарт или фальшстарт?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "фальШстарт" (что мне кажется логичнее) или "фальстарт"?

Answer (score 2):

Фальстарт. Слово заимствованное, в английском Ш нет.
Не понимаю как связано пожелание заимствовать еще и английское произношение гласного.
начнем с того, что язык не обязан следовать фонетике языка источника, но обычно делает это тогда, когда его собственная (языка-приемника) не противоречит исходной. 
А во-вторых, в конкретном случае [О] в английском - позиционно обусловленное исключение, не правило.

Answer (score 1):

Фальстарт. Согласно, по меньшей мере, словарям Ушакова, Ожегова и словарю иностранных слов русского языка

Comment: Да. Но хорошо бы давать ссылки, все эти словари есть в сети.

Answer (score 0):

1) **Фальстарт** ― англ. false start, в переводе ― ошибочный старт, произношение |fɔːls|, но интересно то, что английский и американский варианты произношения различаются (сходство с А или О)  [False | wooordhunt.ru](http://wooordhunt.ru/word/false).

Поэтому русский вариант "фальстарт" никак не противоречит первоисточнику.

2) Вариант **"фальшстарт"** не используется, так как может восприниматься как сокращенное "фальшивый старт", а прилагательное "фальшивый" (поддельный, ложный, ненастоящий, искаженный и др.) не лучшим образом  передаёт значение "преждевременный".

А откуда берется Ш в слове "фальшивый"? Это др.-рус. заимствование из польского языка, которое восходит к латыни: falsus ― ложный,  от  fallere ― обманывать.

Comment: Собственно, английское *false* также восходит к латинскому *falsus*. Вообще, зачем последний абзац вашего ответа? В нем нет объяснения, почему вдруг звук *ш* появился. Нужно написать, что, поскольку заимствование из польского *faɫszywy*, где звукосочетание *sz* произносится как русский *ш*...

Comment: И, кстати, не различаются произносительные варианты брит. и амер. Незначительно, во всяком случае.